# PCA scores in my own implementation have different sign from the ones computed in R

Tags: r, pca, excel

I am trying to implement PCA (NIPALS method) using Excel. The problem is that my results are not exactly matching with the results of R. There is only a difference in sign: if my scores are positive, then scores using R are negative.

I don't know what is going on. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

1) I wouldn't use Excel for data analysis

2) The signs of PCA are arbitrary, so there is no real problem here.

Comment: Oh, Is it so. Ill see to it. Thank you so much Peter.